# How can create Database connection for pdo using classes

Tags: java, php, mysql

How can i create database connection to access the another files in pdo. I am using the class in one file and want to use in the another the file class. please tell me that how can i use only one database connection for multiple files. Below is my code:
Database.php for connection and userinfo.php for accesing any data from the database.
            ****database.php****
      code for connection:

```
        public $dbconnect;
        public $database="mysql";
        public $host="localhost";
        public $username="root";
        public $password="root"; //put your db password
        public $databasename="dbweb";

       public function __construct($dbconnect){
            $this->dbconnect=$dbconnect;
        }
        public function pdocon(){
            if($this->database=='mysql'){
                try{
                    $this->dbconnect=new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->databasename",$this->username,$this->password);
                    echo"connected";
                }catch(PDOException $eobject){
                    die('Error Connection Database: ' .$eobject->getMessage());
                    echo"Not Connected";
                }

            }
    }
    }
    ?>

This is another file where i want to display the data from database:

****userinfo.php****
    <?php
    include_once'database.php';
    class c extends connect{

    function aa()
    {
        $obj=new connect();
        $pdconnect=$obj->pdocon();
        echo $obj->databasename;

        $sql = $pdoconnect->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id='3'");
       $result = $pdoconnect->exec($sql);
         while ($row = $result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
           echo $row['username'];
           echo $row['firstname'];
           echo $row['lastname'];
          }


    }
    }
    $a=new c();
    $a->aa();

    ?>
please tell me the appropriate solution for this.
```

Comment: My mind-reading abilities tell me that your variable isn't global!

Comment: post some code ... we are not fortune tellers

Comment: i am using this file to connect the database:

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you put your code so that we can know how you are doing and find any mistakes and on top of that we can know what is you are asking exactly.

but here is how i was doing it.

```
<?php
class dbconnect{

    protected $dbconnect;
    private $database="mysql";
    private $host="localhost";
    private $username="root";
    private $password="nopassword1"; //put your db password
    private $databasename="iit1";

    function __construct(){

        if($this->database=='mysql'){
            try{
                $this->dbconnect=new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->databasename",$this->username,$this->password);
            }catch(PDOException $eobject){
                die('Error Connection Database: ' .$eobject->getMessage());
            }

        }
    }
}

?>
```